# Adding space before the second line of the Text break

Tags: html, css

How to add space before the second line of the div text without using `@nbsp;`

**Current**

[image]

**Expected**

[image]

```css
div{
  width:200px;
}
div::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #a6a9aa;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div> Some Long Long Link Text will come Here </div>
```

Comment: What about `<ul>`/`<ol>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<ul>` instead

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: circle;
}

li {
  max-width: 150px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia
    animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda
    est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis
    voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
  </li>
  <li>
    At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia
    animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda
    est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis
    voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
  </li>
  <li>
    At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia
    animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda
    est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis
    voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
div{
  width:200px;
  
  margin-left: 15px;
}
div::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #a6a9aa;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    
    
    margin: auto 5px auto -15px;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
```

Try this.

Answer (score 1):

check this. hope it help

```css
div{          
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 18px;
    width:200px;
}
div::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #a6a9aa;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div> Some Long Long Link Text will come Here </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **CSS Positioning** to achieve this, make your `div` positioned `relative` & `div::before` positioned `absolute`. Like:

```
div {
  width:200px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  position: relative;
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: 0;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
div{
  width:200px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  position: relative;
}
div::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #a6a9aa;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>Some Long Long Link Text will come Here</div>
```

> By the way, you can also use `<ul></ul>` for this.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
    width:200px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

div::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #a6a9aa;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div> Some Long Long Link Text will come Here </div>
```